# sorting of dataframe based on condition and return all the group by assigning to random vector dynamically

Tags: python, r, dataframe

For example: **INPUT DATAFRAME** is:-

```
INPUT     group
4000       1
4000       1
2000       2
3000       3
2000       4
2000       4
2000       4
```

Output :- dynamically assign to any random vector and generate output as:-
First dataframe with maximum repeated group number, Second dataframe with second highest element of repeated group,and so on…

**OUTPUT**
**1.First**

```
INPUT     group
2000        4
2000        4
2000        4
```

**2.second**

```
INPUT        group
4000        1
4000        1
```

**3.third**

```
INPUT        group
2000        2
```

**4.fourth**

```
INPUT        group
3000        3
```

in more simple words- i want to divide dataframe into some groups and in results i want all the groups in ascending order by assigning to some variables.
I tried with so far is this:

```
x<-setDT(df)[, group := rleid(df$INPUT)]
```

this will sort the group. i tried one more comand, that is:

```
y<-x[x$group == which.max(tabulate(x$group)), ]
```

but this returns only group with maximum number of repeated group element.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the relevant information there, not in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean with 'any random vector'?

Comment: Is `python` related here in any way?

Comment: @heroka   like this  y<-x[x$group == which.max(tabulate(x$group)), ],  here y is that random vector or variable or any thing..so if dataframe is divided in 4 group, I want to assign each group to some varable so that in later phase i can use all of them for processing.

Comment: @David Arenburg, I am right now looking for some good R script, but if problem can be solved in python also then most welcome...i am eagerly waiting.

Comment: Filling your environment with numerous data frames is a bad idea. Why would you need this?

Comment: @David, I know this but some times it is necessary to see even a smallest element behaviour, if it can impact the overall infrastructure, can u suggest me something with this little bit of information. in more simple words- i want to divide dataframe into some groups and in results i want all the groups in ascending order by assigning to some variables.

Comment: @india Check answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether you need all your outputs at once or not. But here is an idea that might help. I am using the dplyr package for this. So first let me recreate the dataset you provided as input:

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(INPUT = c(4000,4000,2000,3000,2000,2000,2000), group = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4))
df <- tbl_df(DF)
df
```

#### output

```
  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  4000     1
2  4000     1
3  2000     2
4  3000     3
5  2000     4
6  2000     4
7  2000     4
```

Now I will create an auxiliary table which will tell me how many rows I have of each group, this table will be already ordered from max to min:

```
aux <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% arrange(-n)
aux
```

#### output

```
  group     n
  (dbl) (int)
1     4     3
2     1     2
3     2     1
4     3     1
```

So we see that group 4 appears 3 times, group 1 appears twice and so on and so forth.
Now I can easily "extract" the groups I want from max to min:

```
ymax <- df %>% filter(group == aux$group[1])
y2 <- df %>% filter(group == aux$group[2])
y3 <- df %>% filter(group == aux$group[3])
ymin <- df %>% filter(group == aux$group[4])
```

#### output

```
ymax
  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  2000     4
2  2000     4  
3  2000     4  

y2
  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  4000     1
2  4000     1  

y3
  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  2000     2  

ymin
  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  3000     3
```

I hope this helps.
I just want to add that you can get all of them at once of course:

```
ylist <- lapply(1:nrow(aux), function(x) {filter(df, group == aux$group[x])})
```

#### output

```
[[1]]
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  2000     4
2  2000     4
3  2000     4

[[2]]
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  4000     1
2  4000     1

[[3]]
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  2000     2

[[4]]
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

  INPUT group
  (dbl) (dbl)
1  3000     3
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python Pandas you could do the following:

create the DF:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['INPUT'] = [4000,4000,2000,3000,2000,2000,2000]
df['group'] = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
```

Group by group and get the size of each group, add this size to DF as a column and sort by it in ascending order:

```
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group').size()).reset_index()).sort_values(0,ascending=False)
```

Then, loop through the DF to get the part you need each time:

```
for i,x in enumerate(df['group'].unique()):
print 'ouput',i
print df[df['group']==x].ix[:,:-1].reset_index(drop=True)
print
```

This give you the following:

```
    ouput 0
    INPUT  group
0   2000      4
1   2000      4
2   2000      4

    ouput 1
    INPUT  group
0   4000      1
1   4000      1

    ouput 2
    INPUT  group
0   2000      2

    ouput 3
    INPUT  group
0   3000      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr India - Try This.

```
library(sqldf)
Input=c('4000','4000','2000','3000','2000','2000','2000')   
gr<-c('1','1','2','3','4','4','4')
DF<-data.frame(Input,gr)
NewDF<-data.frame()
DF<-sqldf("select  distinct Input, gr, count(*) as C from DF group by Input, gr order by C desc")
for (i in 1:nrow(DF))
  assign(paste("NewDF_",i,sep=""),na.omit(DF[i,][rep(row.names(DF), DF$C), 1:2]))
```

This will create 4 different Dataframes with your desired output.